# Javascript not functioning inside of my HTML. no scrolling in parallax website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code I have. I am completely new to coding, and trying to build a parralax website. Basically its supposed the move layer1, and layer2 upon scrolling. However the Javascript I am running is not working. in the developer tools it runs the error code of: "uncaught reference error window.pageYOFFset is not defined. I tried fixing it myself  but I am at a loss. Any explanation of what I am doing wrong would be  appreciated. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
body {margin:0;
    padding:0;}
.zoom{
    width:100%;
    height: 1000px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(/Users/reinh/Downloads/bg\ \(2\).jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.zoom:before{
    content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
z-index: 1000;
background:linear-gradient(transparent,#fff);

}

.zoom #layer1{
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index:10;

}
.zoom #layer2{
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9;
}
.zoom #text

{
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
.content { 

    padding: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: consolas;
}
 .content h2 {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:4em;

 }
 .content p{
    font-size: 1.2em;
 }

    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Johnathan Reinhart </title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="zoom">
        <img src="/Users/reinh/Downloads/mountain1.png" id="layer1">
        <img src="/Users/reinh/Downloads/mountain2.png" id="layer2">
        <img src="/Users/reinh/Downloads/text.png" id="text">
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <h2> Simple Background paralax place holder text!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur molestias placeat ad nihil expedita accusamus nulla laudantium eveniet dolore molestiae! Sed commodi minima aut laboriosam dolorem voluptates eaque asperiores nulla.
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis vel perspiciatis ad provident. Velit provident laborum accusamus unde error illum harum repellat iure deserunt ad perspiciatis, porro dignissimos sapiente odio! 
            <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Magni voluptatum similique tenetur rerum expedita illum optio, temporibus voluptate doloremque accusamus, eaque repudiandae mollitia voluptatem dicta vero id minima. Tempora, nulla.
        </p>

    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1")
        scroll= window.pageYOFFset;
        document.addEventListener('scroll',
        function (e) {
        var offset = window.pageYOFFset;
        scroll = offset;
        layer1.style.width = (100 + scroll/5)+ '%' ;
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the Layer1, and Layer2 to move along their respectives axis upon scrolling. However nothing happened. I was absolutely 100% sure my doe was good, and so I tried different syntax, and checked to make sure Javascript was enabled in my browser. No fix

Answer (score 0):

dont you mean [window.pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset)?.

By convention, javascript uses the camel case notation for everything, even, vsCode should give you hints about the properties that you want to write.